# Screen artifacts from installation persist in GRUB / Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu in dual boot mode using something like this walk-through (maybe this exact one) [Install Ubuntu 14.04 in Dual Boot Mode with Windows 8/8.1 UEFI | itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)

I was having graphics issues so I booted in recovery mode in Ubuntu and then uninstalled the nvidia drivers and ran the following commands to update:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390 nvidia-prime
```

That fixed the resolution issues and everything looked much better.

The problem was that I left the USB stick in and it booted to the installation menu again and I couldn't figure out how to get it to restart so I did a hard restart.

Now on the GRUB menu and everywhere in Ubuntu I can clearly see flickering which includes the last menu I was looking at before doing a hard restart (it is the partition screen in the boot process if you are curious; I can make out everything it says)

Any ideas? This persists between boots and even when I boot into Windows 10 and reboot back to the GRUB menu I see it clear as day again.  Anything that has any shading at all flickers the menu like crazy and makes Ubuntu unusable.

Comment: Try the `nvidia-387` drivers instead.  I was using the 390 and they seemed really unstable and were causing artifacts and videos were having major issues with it too.

Comment: Wow you are right that worked to fix it.